# Is ther a var_dump implementation for objects that may take > 2GB of ram?

Tags: php, debugging

For debugging purpoces once I do `var_dump` it may take > 2GB of ram if I develop upon magento.

Therefore I am looking an alternative to inspect an object and its contents either without modifying php settings or codebase.

What I was thinking as a snippet where I can copy/paste upon the code and use it.

Comment: Maybe use print_r and send to a file instead? Why do you need to inspect a 2GB variable anyway?

Comment: [var_export()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export) will be the best choice for me.

Comment: Still var_export will cause ram to blowup. Is could read the object sequencially and write it into the same time.

Comment: Magento has a lot of recursion and extra stuff in their objects. I'd probably json_encode it or serialize it before you dump it.

Comment: What about using xdebug?

Comment: If I had it in my remote setup that I do not manage.The issue is circular references.

Comment: And whatever problem you are trying to debug here, can't be reproduced locally?

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using? Magento now has `dd` and `dump` functions that usually work on anything, and if the variable volume exceeds a specific limit, it will display less depth.

Comment: I am using magento2.3

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider how you're using var_dump if you'll be dumping that much data. However, you might want to consider

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Which is an improved var_dumper tool which will also help format and manage large objects. It is a standalone component that is also part of the Symfony framework. Among other things it provide ways to dump data outside of simply the web interface. Additionally you might also want to look at XDebug instead.